# Request throughput between Graviton instances ( C7xLarge vx C72xLarge)

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk

**Question**: I have multiple(roughly 8) Ec2 C7xLarge instances which can comfortably handle 2500 to 3000 requests/per second. I am running this using an Elastic Beanstalk environment. In terms of throughput, can I achieve twice the same throughput if I opt for 4 EC2 C72xLarge instances?

Reverse proxy used : nginx

The reason for changing these instances because we have some kind of discount for 2xLarge instances.

**Configuration difference between instances**

[Instance comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFjHA.png)

[Instance ulimit ,open files properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdLCx.png)

Comment: Half the number of machines with twice the capacity will probably give you similar capacity to what you have now. You will need to benchmark to work out if your application scales with additional cores / RAM.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the input.I had to performance testing and benchmarks the numbers between different types of instances